# Why doesn't the resizeToFit work?

Tags: ios7, uilabel

I have a Second View in a storyboard. When the button in the 1st View is pressed, the 2nd View will be load. There're 2 UILabels in the 2nd view and their texts are set and [label resizeToFit] in viewDidLoad. However, I can only find the texts set without resizeToFit working. What's the reason about that? And how should I set the label to appropriate size when loading?

my resizeToFit function comes from: https://gist.github.com/danielphillips/1005520

It does work in some other conditions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with resizeToFit, but I have used the normal sizeToFit function with success. Have you tried that? Did you put the sizeToFit in viewDidLoad?

Comment: It failes too. Moreover, actually I just to resize the height, but not the width.